# Neo4j Cypher query sort order

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j/SDN project I have a following mode:

`Decision` entity that contains child `Decision` and `Characteristic` entities.

Each pair of child `Decision` and `Characteristic`  can have a Value node assigned.

I have created 3 child `Decision` nodes, for example

```
childDecision1
childDecision2
childDecision3
```

and one `Characteristic`:

characterisitc1

I have assigned following values to the following pairs:

```
childDecision2 + characterisitc1 = Value(Integer 10)
childDecision3 + characterisitc1 = Value(Integer 25)
```

I'm executing the following Cypher query(with O`RDER BY sortValue88.value ASC`):

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue88:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic88:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(sortCharacteristic88) = 88
WITH ru, u, childD , sortValue88 
ORDER BY sortValue88.value ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

As the result I have:

```
childDecision2 (Value = 10)
childDecision3 (Value = 25)
childDecision1 (no value provided)
```

So far everything works fine.

Right now I'm going to change the sort order direction from `ASC` to `DESC`:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId}
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue88:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic88:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(sortCharacteristic88) = 88
WITH ru, u, childD , sortValue88 
ORDER BY sortValue88.value DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 100 
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

As the result I have:

```
childDecision1 (no value provided)
childDecision3 (Value = 25)
childDecision2 (Value = 10)
```

Right now I don't understand why the childDecision1 hold the first place but I expect childDecision3 instead there.

Could you please help to explain/fix this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because: [`When sorting the result set, null will always come at the end of the result set for ascending sorting, and first when doing descending sort.`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/order-by/#order-by-ordering-null)

So you need to know the minimum possible value for sorting. For example, if all values are not less than zero

```
WITH [1, 0, 2, NULL, 4] AS CS
UNWIND RANGE(0, size(CS)-1) as i
RETURN i, 
       CASE WHEN CS[i] IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE CS[i] END AS sortValue
ORDER BY sortValue DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any chance to reconfigure Neo4j in order to return NULL last  when doing descending sort ? I have a pretty heavy query and additional conditions in my opinion is not a pretty good choice

Comment: You can change code of `CypherOrderability.compare` function [ https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/862d62b2f2dc2221e48476ac1f6c93c91d7d6015/community/cypher/cypher-compiler-3.2/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v3_2/common/CypherOrderability.java#L105 ] or is it a good reason to request a new feature.

Comment: Thanks! created a github issue https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9213